# PHP exec not executing command

Tags: php, exec

I have used php's exec to execute FFmpeg command but its not woking when I open it in browser. But when i run this php file script in terminal it works fine.And my php safe mode is off. please help me to get it solved. my php code is

```
<?php
$output=exec("ffmpeg -f image2 -i /home/phedra/imgs/image/img%03d.png -r 12 -s 610x489 /home/phedra/imgs/video/out.avi", $out);
echo $out;
echo $output;
?>
```

Comment: My first guess is there is permission issue. Can you put your code here and the output of executing the command through exec

Comment: Yep, exec command issues are almost always permission problems.

Comment: @rakeshjain i Have included my php code and i have tried to get the output but it is not giving any result. check my code i have edited it.

Comment: you didn't get anything in $out array?

Comment: no its just printing 'Array' nothing else

Comment: @Alifaizan if it is giving you an array then to dump using print_r($output); or print_r($out);  and what it returns.

Comment: @arfeen it is returning an empty array

Comment: one more thing do we have to use a different package of ffmpeg if we want to execute its command in php? and I am using simple ffmpeg package.

Answer (score 6):

try giving full path where the ffmpeg application is located.

e.g.

```
/usr/bin/ffmpeg
```

So your function might look like:

```
$output=exec("/usr/bin/ffmpeg -f image2 -i /home/phedra/imgs/image/img%03d.png -r 12 -s 610x489 /home/phedra/imgs/video/out.avi", $out);
```

You must check what is the location of "ffmpeg".

Comment: @Alifaizan Have you put the correct path since the one I gave you is just an example.

Comment: `su www-data` or whatever your apache user is and try to run ffmpeg from ssh it maybe a permission issue.

Answer (score 3):

I had this problem and it turned out it was Apache's permission on the public directory.

**Note:** I am running Ubuntu 14 on AWS

After installing FFmpeg I had to change the `/var/www/*` ownership to `www-data`.

```
sudo chown -R www-data:root /var/www
```

(the `www-data` is the important part here)

Then I had the following code running, and it works when I access it via URL (Apache)

```
// test.php

$run = system("/opt/ffmpeg/bin/ffmpeg -i /var/www/html/input.mp4 -vf scale=640:480 /var/www/html/output.mp4 &");

if($run) {
    echo "success";
} else {
    echo "failed";
}
```

The `/opt/ffmpeg/bin/ffmpeg` is where my FFmpeg is running from. Yours might be `/usr/bin/ffmpeg` or something else. You can locate it by typing `locate ffmpeg` in the command line and looking through the list it gives you.

The input file was a public .mp4 file and the output.mp4 file was going to the same location.

Run this in your command line: `php test.php` - works
Run this from your browser: yourwebsite.com/test.php - works

Comment: Dude you saved me a lot of headaches :D that worked for me on Ubuntu 18.04. I tried different options, but nothing worked until this.

Answer (score 0):

Note that if you are on windows you must use COMMAS. I.E:

```
$output=exec('"/usr/bin/ffmpeg" -f image2 -i /home/phedra/imgs/image/img%03d.png -r 12 -s 610x489 /home/phedra/imgs/video/out.avi', $out);
```

Answer (score 0):

Like @Arfeen mentioned in his answer, you should execute the command with the path of ffmpeg, but, the given path in the answer "/usr/bin/ffmpeg" is not always the same.

First locate your ffmpeg by using the command :

```
which ffmpeg
```

The result in my case is :

> /usr/local/bin/ffmpeg

Then go back to your php code and replace "ffmpeg" in the command by the path of ffmpeg (which is /usr/local/bin/ffmpeg in my case).