# FFMpeg working in command line but not in PHP script

Tags: php, video, ffmpeg, flv, server

I am using FFMpeg to convert videos and it is working fine from the command line. I am using the following command:

```
ffmpeg -i input.avi -ab 56 -ar 44100 -b 200 -r 15 -s 320x240 -f flv output.flv
```

However, when I run the command using PHP script, the output video is not encoded.

```
exec("ffmpeg -i input.avi -ab 56 -ar 44100 -b 200 -r 15 -s 320x240 -f flv output.flv",$output, $returnvalue);

$returnvalue = 127;
```

**FFMPEG installed path :**

```
[root@localhost ~]# which ffmpeg

/root/bin/ffmpeg
```

**My Script Path :**

www.domainname.com/core/foldername/ffmpeg.php

Please provide me solution for the same ASAP.

Thank you.

Answer (score 7):

The natural way to run `ffmpeg` from PHP scripts is something like:

```
<?php
    echo "Starting ffmpeg...\n\n";
    echo shell_exec("ffmpeg -i input.avi output.avi &");
    echo "Done.\n";
?>
```

There are several issues that need to be pointed out here. The first one is that, although we specified we want `ffmpeg` to be executed in the background (using the ampersand operator "&"), PHP script will **not continue** it's execution until `ffmpeg` has finished its execution. This is due to the fact, mentioned in one of the notes for the ​PHP's `exec()` function that says:

> If a program is started with this function, in order for it to
>   continue running in the background, the output of the program must be
>   redirected to a file or another output stream. Failing to do so will
>   cause PHP to hang until the execution of the program ends.

Don't be confused about the example showing ​`shell_exec()` call instead of `​exec()`. All of the ​PHP's Program execution functions **share the similar code base** and limitations.

So, to work around this issue, we need to do something like this:

```
<?php
    echo "Starting ffmpeg...\n\n";
    echo shell_exec("ffmpeg -i input.avi output.avi >/dev/null 2>/dev/null &");
    echo "Done.\n";
?>
```

The part that says **">/dev/null"** will redirect the standard OUTPUT (stdout) of the `ffmpeg` instance to `/dev/null` (effectively ignoring the output) and **"2>/dev/null"** will redirect the standard ERROR (stderr) to `/dev/null` (effectively ignoring any error log messages). These two can be combined into a shorter representation: **">/dev/null 2>&1"**. If you like, you can ​read more about I/O Redirection.

An important note should be mentioned here. The `ffmpeg` command-line tool uses `stderr` for output of error log messages and `stdout` is reserved for possible use of pipes (to redirect the output media stream generated from `ffmpeg` to some other command line tool). That being said, if you run your `ffmpeg` in the background, you'll most probably want to redirect the `stderr` to a log file, to be able to check it later.

One more thing to take care about is the standard INPUT (stdin). Command-line `ffmpeg` tool is designed as an interactive utility that accepts user's input (usually from keyboard) and reports the error log on the user's current screen/terminal. When we run `ffmpeg` in the background, we want to tell `ffmpeg` that no input should be accepted (nor waited for) from the `stdin`. We can tell this to `ffmpeg`, using I/O redirection again ** "ffmpeg command-line tool in the background would be similar to this:

```
<?php
    echo "Starting ffmpeg...\n\n";
    echo shell_exec("ffmpeg -y -i input.avi output.avi </dev/null >/dev/null 2>/var/log/ffmpeg.log &");
    echo "Done.\n";
?>
```

The ​**"-y"** option is used to auto-overwrite the output file (output.avi) without asking for `yes/no` confirmation. If you need the opposite scenario, to auto-cancel the entire process if the output file already exists, then use **"-n"** option instead.

**Wrapper Libraries**

Some PHP libraries allow wrapping `ffmpeg` calls into PHP objects, and give you a nice syntax to work with if you don't like to use the command line. One of these is the actively maintained ​[PHP-FFMpeg](https://github.com/PHP-FFMpeg/PHP-FFMpeg/). It only requires you to ​download a recent `ffmpeg` and `ffprobe` build apart from installing the PHP components. Then you can run PHP code like this:

```
$ffmpeg = FFMpeg\FFMpeg::create();
$video = $ffmpeg->open('video.mpg');
$video
    ->filters()
    ->resize(new FFMpeg\Coordinate\Dimension(320, 240))
    ->synchronize();
$video
    ->save(new FFMpeg\Format\Video\X264(), 'export-x264.mp4')
```

Of course you need to take care of running such a task in the background. Libraries such as ​[GearmanClient](http://php.net/manual/de/gearmanclient.addtaskbackground.php) facilitate this.

**Note:** ​[ffmpeg-php](http://ffmpeg-php.sourceforge.net/) is an extension that is not developed since 2007 (and requires **"ffmpeg-0.4.9_pre1 or higher"**), which means that you are restricted to use a very old version of ffmpeg, without possibility to update it to the latest version. Since a lot of changes/improvements are being made, inside `ffmpeg's` code, every day, it makes `ffmpeg-php` incompatible with the latest `ffmpeg`.

Read the [official documentation](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Using%20FFmpeg%20from%20PHP%20scripts) for more info.

Answer (score 3):

I covered the solution that helps most people that I spoke to about this in another thread.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/38626752/2074077

Essentially, your user needs access to the public directories.

```
<?php 
   exec('whoami'); // Gives you the running user; often it's www-data
?>
```

Then change your public ownership to the `whoami` user.

```
sudo chown -R www-data:root /var/www
```

Comment: This is the right answer! Thanks for sharing!

Answer (score 2):

This happened to me, I found this on another forum; the trick inside of PHP is to give the absolute path to FFMPEG. Try running it like this..

```
exec("/root/bin/ffmpeg -i input.avi -ab 56 -ar 44100 -b 200 -r 15 -s 320x240 -f flv output.flv",$output, $returnvalue);
```

Something about the fact that php is a different user than you are when typing straight into the command line. I guess it doesn't have the same shortcut list or whatever it is.

Not sure exactly why but it worked for me!

Good luck.