# php call scrapy by custom command

Tags: php, python, cmd, scrapy

I have to run my five different scrapy spiders at the same time so I define a custom command in scrapy like

```
scrapy crawlall
```

to call these spiders. It works successfully when I run in command line in independent.

However it fails when I use php shell_exec to call the same command and the code in php file is like

```
$cmd = 'scrapy crawlall';
$results = shell_exec($cmd);
echo $results;
```

The web page will echo nothing immediately and not waiting the scrapy function(or even it wasn't be called at the beginning I don't know). So how can I call this command or other way to run these 5 spiders at the same time in php file? Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP exec not executing command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18608207/php-exec-not-executing-command)

Comment: I found that the command was called and excute but stop by it self at: `[scrapy.extensions.telnet] DEBUG: Telnet console listening on 127.0.0.1:6023` Does anyone know what's going on?

Comment: Are you sure it is working until then? Can you try running `scrapy list` from PHP and see if it returns the expected spiders?

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the problem. If you get the same situation, try to remove all comment in your command python file. I don't know the reason but after I do that it works successful.